# How to deploy a tailwind project without losing its originality?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I completed my first tailwind project and I worked on it by opening it on my VSS live server. However, after I finished working on the project and deployed it on github and netlify, the website looks slightly different. For example, the nav bar is compressed and also any other such components.

My first screenshot is of how the website looks in my VSS live server.

[image: This is how the website looks like in my VSS live server]

The second screenshot is of how it looks once it's deployed or even after I open it directly in Chrome from local storage.

[image: deployed site]

I have worked very hard on this and I want it to deploy as it shows in my live server and I am unable to understand why there is such a big difference.

This is the link to my github code: https://github.com/ajayksuresh/ineuron-paytm-clone

This is the deployed link: https://aj-paytm-clone.netlify.app/

Please note that I used tailwind by installing it using npm.

Comment: Try pressing command-0 (zero) on your deployed site restore the default zoom level. If I go to your live site it looks like your dev, and when I zoom in with command-+ It looks like the screenshot of your deployed site. So it works fine :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Gabe. This fixed the issue when I open the index file from my local storage. I was busting my head on what was going wrong. However is the production, the default screen still shows as my error screenshot, but when I zoom out to 90%, it's exactly as how I want it to be. :) Do you think this is just how it displays on different screens? You were super helpful!

Comment: Yes, if you make the browser screen less wide it will also look like the second screenshot. You can change this by using breakpoints (like md and lg) and use a smaller font size for smaller breakpoints, like `text-sm md:text-lg g:text-xl`. See: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#responsive and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcK38Simjaw